# Is there a way to include github3.py as an Ansible Playbook library or module, without installing via pip?

Tags: ansible, github3.py

My playbook needs to be able to support adding a tag to a github repository when a production deployment is performed. The intent is to automate the generation of a release tag via Ansible's built in github_release module as a local action on the Ansible server. The documentation on the module is clear, and straight forward, that this module requires the github3.py Python module.

The issue I'm running into at this point is that our "CICD Operators" do not believe that the github3.py module needs to be installed on the Ansible server. The belief is that 'github3.py' can be put into the /library directory and the module is available no matter what server it runs on. This seems logical based on my limited understanding of Ansible playbook libraries; however, github3 is not just a simple Python script that can be copied into a directory.

Everything I've found shows that this needs to be installed on the server via PIP. Is that the only way to do this, or am I missing some fundamental process to take the source tar ball and add it as a local playbook library? I've tried extracting the source to ./library and even created symbolic links to different points in the structure.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/github_release_module.html

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#bundling-ansible-modules-with-playbooks

https://pypi.org/project/github3.py/1.3.0/

```
/playbook $ ls
ansible.cfg  checkConnectivity.yml  gitTagging.yml  library  roles  site.yml
/playbook $ ls -la library/
... dedup_list.py
... github3 -> /home/#####/AppEng_Ansible_Playbook/playbook/library/github3.py-1.3.0/src/github3
... github3.py -> /home/#####/AppEng_Ansible_Playbook/playbook/library/github3.py-1.3.0/src/github3
... github3.py-1.3.0
... github3.py-1.3.0.tar.gz
```

```
/playbook $ cat ansible.cfg
[default]
library = ./library
#github3.py = ./library/github3.py
#github3.py = ./library/github3
#github3 = ./library/github3
```

```
/playbook $ cat gitTagging.yml
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Local Action - Create Tag
    local_action:
      module: github_release
      user: XYZ
      password: #####
      action: create_release
      repo: git@repo.XXXXX.com:Enterprise-Communications/web_php_cicd_testing.git
      tag: MyTag
      target: v0.0.9rc
      name: Ansible Test
      body: Test 1
    run_once: true
```

```
ansible-playbook 2.8.2
...
...
TASK [Local Action - Create Tag] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/#####/AppEng_Ansible_Playbook/playbook/gitTagging.yml:14
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: #####
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~##### && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/#####/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1568051389.77-61244317218380 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1568051389.77-61244317218380="` echo /home/#####/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1568051389.77-61244317218380 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/source_control/github_release.py
<localhost> PUT /home/#####/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-228190qaU7p/tmptpN1cj TO /home/#####/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1568051389.77-61244317218380/AnsiballZ_github_release.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/#####/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1568051389.77-61244317218380/ /home/#####/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1568051389.77-61244317218380/AnsiballZ_github_release.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /home/#####/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1568051389.77-61244317218380/AnsiballZ_github_release.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/#####/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1568051389.77-61244317218380/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_github_release_payload_fZHzWp/__main__.py", line 134, in <module>
    import github3
ImportError: No module named github3

fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "action": "create_release",
            "body": "Test 1",
            "draft": false,
            "name": "Ansible Test",
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "prerelease": false,
            "repo": "git@repo.XXXXX.com:Enterprise-Communications/web_php_cicd_testing.git",
            "tag": "MyTag",
            "target": "v0.0.9rc",
            "token": null,
            "user": "XYZ"
        }
    },
    "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (github3.py >= 1.0.0a3) on led####'s Python /usr/bin/python. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the playbook install the necessary dependency into a temporary virtualenv, then use the remainder of the playbook to execute against that venv:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - raw: |
     if [ -x /tmp/bob/bin/python ]; then exit 0; fi
     /usr/local/bin/python3 -m venv --prompt tmp /tmp/bob
     .  /tmp/bob/bin/activate
     /tmp/bob/bin/pip install --upgrade 'github3.py >= 1.0.0a3'

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /tmp/bob/bin/python
  tasks:
  - github_release:
      user: ansible
      repo: ansible
      action: latest_release
```

(substituting your own `hosts:` and `connection:`; I just used localhost and local for testing whether such a thing would work, and the answer that it does)

It may even be possible to do such a thing in a role, to have some cleanup action or whatever, but I didn't take it that far

Comment: Thank you for the solution!
I'll talk to our group, but I don't think they'll like the idea of the playbook creating and tearing down a virtual environment several dozen times a day.

Comment: Well, "our CICD Operators do not believe that the github3.py module needs to be installed on the Ansible server" means they can't have their cake and eat it, too; if they'd install the requested library, you wouldn't need a virtualenv. For clarity, you don't **have** to tear down the v-env: you can create it in a well-known place and just leave it there. I guess it depends on how frequently you're doing releases whether it becomes a serious drag on velocity to install that pip dependency as needed